# How to add up values of one column until a condition from another column is reached?

Tags: r

I have a matrix like this:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,1,1,3,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1), ncol = 2,
             dimnames = list(NULL, c('var', 'tp')))
     var  tp
[1,]   1  0
[2,]   2  0
[3,]   1  0
[4,]   1  1
[5,]   3  1
[6,]   1  0
[7,]   1  1
etc.
```

I'd like to sum up all lines of `var` until `tp` becomes 1, then print the result and stop. In this example, that would mean summing up the first four lines.

How would I do this in R?

Comment: `sum(m[1:match(1, m[, "tp"]), "var"])`?

Comment: Or `sum(m[1:which.max(m[, "tp"] == 1), "var"])`

Comment: When I run one of these on one of the later lines, it seems not to start from that line but from line 1. Is there a way to make sum start on another line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the cumsum function to identify at which row tp becomes 1, then find the row with which, and sum var to this point

```
 sum(X[1:min(which(cumsum(m[,2])==1)),1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
cumsum(m[, 1])[cumsum(m[,2 ]) ==1 ] # or
cumsum(m[, 'var'])[cumsum(m[, 'tp']) == 1]
```